# Bash - Strange behavior when assigning `find` result to variable

Tags: macos, bash, shell, find

I am attempting to do some simple directory mangling via a bash script, but I am encountering some odd behavior (OSX 10.6).

When I issue the following command within the target directory, I get the expected results from the `find` command when attempting to search for just directories/folders, ie:

```
find . -iname "*" -type d

Results:
dir1
dir2
dir3
```

However, when I attempt to assign the results to a variable and print it, I get some very different behavior:

```
myvar=$(find . -iname "*" -type d)
echo $myvar

Results:
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir3
dir3
dir3
```

Does it make sense that the final entry is repeated multiple times? I am able to remedy this via piping the output to `sort -u` for now, but I wanted to know the root cause of this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the output of `find .`?

Comment: Could you try placing the `$(...)` in double quotes? Don't know if it would help though...

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho Tried that, no luck.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Using `find .` yields the same results in both cases.

Comment: The answer to your question is "No" (Sorry couldn't resist :) I attempted to reproduce the problem and could not. Can you add  the output of ls -l in the directory above dir[123] and the full contents of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with an output error in the `find` command. Now it's showing the following:

```
myvar=$(find . -iname "*" -type d)
echo $myvar
Results:
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir3/subdir1
dir3/subdir2
dir3/subdir3
```

When it was previously showing:

```
Results:
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir3
dir3
dir3
```

I am not sure why the subdirectories were not being shown, but I have guaranteed that I don't need to use `sort -u` now by specifying the depth as well:

```
myvar=$(find . -iname "*" -type d -maxdepth 1)
Results:
dir1
dir2
dir3
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 echo "$myvar"
```

to verify the output. Without parentheses, an `*` might get evaluated.